# Business Objects and dynamic sql

Tags: .net, sql, dynamic-sql, business-objects

I had this idea and my first reaction after having it was "That's a great idea, but why have I never seen/heard it talked about before??"  So I'm hoping you can tell me if there is some framework out there that already does this, or if there is some reason why I should avoid it.

The idea is to create a base business object class with methods to dynamically write CRUD sql queries based on the name of the derived class and its properties (or aliases specified in  attributes).

My thinking is that once I do this I could just create a new class like so:

```
class Customer: BusinessObjectBase
{
    int Id {get;set;}
    string Name {get;set;}
    string Phone {get;set;}
}
```

and my Customer class, having access to BusinessObjectBase's CRUD methods, would be done.

Somethings to keep in mind when answering this:  For the sake of this question I'm highly interested in the design goals of decreased development time and low maintenance, and security is about a 3 on a scale of 1 to 10.  In other words, I'm not interested in hearing answers telling me I should be using stored procedures to access data because they are more secure, or anything along those lines.

I know the users here are pretty liberal with the close votes when it comes to overly broad questions... so just to be safe let me reiterate the question, which is not too broad:

Are there any existing frameworks to do this or is there any compelling reason why I should not?

Comment: You are very much reinventing yet another ORM here.  It's fun if you haven't done it before, but if you aren't doing it for fun, it's a complete waste of time when there are high quality, feature rich ORMs already available.  You will be creating a very feature poor, incomplete, and likely buggy custom ORM that no one other than yourself will love.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has been done before; many times, many ways.   The basic concept your thinking of is called 'model first' development.   You can do model first in Entity Framework, NHibernate, Subsonic and many other ORM style-frameworks.    Another incarnation of this line of thinking is LINQ-to-SQL where LINQ knows what queries to generate, whether or not you have CRUD stored procs.

Before ORM's were mainstream we use code files (codified in T4 style templates these days) to write out what your describing.  The whole idea was based on 'convention' meaning if a field is named ID then it must be the clustered-PK and so on.

**Disclaimer**

With that said, there is a down side to this line of thinking.   In your typical web app (or insert your app style here) you have three layers to work with--- client, middle, and DB.  With model/code-first development you are effectively ignoring one of the three layers.   Modern hardware has gotten quick enough that you can do this for most sites.  When your site grows in volume & complexity, however, you will often find yourself working around this auto-crud setup for your most complex/frequently-used scenarios.

Anyway, hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, this is geared towards a win forms POS system and many of the concerns that normally drive these kinds of conversations aren't high priorities, and some of the assumptions (like that there is a real dba on staff who writes/manages stored procs) aren't true either.  So I'm trying to find that middle ground that meets our needs without adding unnecessary overhead.  Like you said, I was sure that this has been done before but I am surprised I haven't found any frameworks in my google searches.  Are you aware of any?

Comment: Entity Framework, NHibernate, and Subsonic are frameworks.   The ideas apply equally well in in winforms/WPF, web app, or POS  scenario.  I don't see why these ideas assume a DBA or add unnecessary overhead.   It's true that leaving the SQL to a framework necessarily wrestles some tuning/optimization control from your hands, but try it and see how it works for you before you work about premature-optimizations.  Or am I missing something?

Comment: @BrandonMoore this might be a useful reference point... http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/16/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4.aspx

Comment: Hmm... perhaps one of us is not completely understand the other.  The idea I have is that the sql is dynamically generated by a base class, but these frameworks require strongly typed classes (even if they have designers to automatically generate/update those classes for you).  I do like Linq2Sql, but I run into issues when I try to create the base class I dream of and I've seen others that have had the same problems.  But the Entity Framework and others have been too cumbersome for my liking.  I work with very inexperienced developers and need something really, really simple.

Comment: I think I see where you're coming from... the frameworks do generate dynamic sql for me. The difference is that, like I said, you have to let their designers generate strongly typed classes for you.  I don't want that. I just want a base class with methods smart enough to create queries based on the name of the derived class/properties.  It's hard to explain the reason I want this in a short comment, but maybe I'll expound on it in an edit in my question tomorrow.  One difference is the approach of mapping classes to the actual schema vs assuming schema based on the class, if that makes sense.

Comment: For something like EF, yes it is based around mapping files & a designer (althogh don't knock it till you've tried it ;-).  Something like NHibernate - a mapping file, although there are bolt on designers.   OTOH, something like Subsonic just looks at your hand coded class files ... watch this 5 min demo ... http://subsonicproject.com/docs/Simple_Repo_5_Minute_Demo

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7102/discussion-between-ebarr-and-brandon-moore)